# Error in Custom Blade Directives with array as parameter

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-blade

In my Laravel 5.7 app I want to use Custom Blade Directives and to pass an array in this directive 
as there could be different access, like :

```
@loggedUserHasAccess([USER_ACCESS_ADMIN])
<div class="col">
    <a class="social-inner" href="{{ route('admin.dashboard') }}" >
        <span class="icon"></span><span>Backend</span>
    </a>
</div>
@endLoggedUserHasAccess
```

And in app/Providers/AppServiceProvider.php :

```
class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    public function boot()
    {

        ...


        \Blade::directive('loggedUserHasAccess', function (array $accessArray) {
            $condition = false;

            if (Auth::check()) {
                $loggedUser  = Auth::user();
                $usersGroups = User::getUsersGroupsByUserId($loggedUser->id, false);
                foreach ($usersGroups as $next_key => $nextUsersGroup) {
                    if (in_array($nextUsersGroup->group_id, $accessArray)) {
                        $condition = true;
                    }
                }
            }
            return "<?php if ($condition) { ?>";
        });

        Blade::directive('endLoggedUserHasAccess', function () {
            return "<?php } ?>";
        });
```

But I got syntax error : https://i.stack.imgur.com/NaUM1.jpg

USER_ACCESS_ADMIN is defined in bootstrap/app.php.
looks like my syntax is invalid, but which is valid ?

Thanks!

Comment: Might be a stupid one, but did u try adding ` \ ` next to the second `Blade`, directive which ends?

Comment: looks that was not reason. Sometimes it works , but unstable. I user clear methods like: php artisan cache:clear
php artisan config:cache
php artisan view:clear
But are there some other clear methods that could help me ?

Comment: Try using `composer dump-autoload` and after that `php artisan optimize`

Comment: I found php artisan  clear-compiled command - can it be it? From my testing it does not like that

Comment: This is an unusual error so I would try it